# How to validate files for multiple extension name checking in ruby or ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am trying to check file for multiple extension name

To check character length, I can do it like below

```
 s= 'hello welcome to stackoverflow'
  if s.length <= 35
     print('okay')
  else
     print('not accepted')
  end
```

**What i want to achieve:**

Now I have a file that i want to check for single, double or multiple extension name.

I only want to allow file names with single extension name. if files has more than one extension name throw error not allowed as can be seen in the code below.

My issue is that I cannot get **dot()** function equivalent of **length()** function

```
   filename = 'nancy.png'

  if filename.length == 1
     print('good file because it has only one dot extension name')
  else
     print('files with two or multiple extension name not allowed')
  end
```

Comment: Can you explain, why I want to ensure such a pattern? In each Rails application there are counter-examples like `application.html.erb`. What is wrong with that? What about names like `.profile`? Valid? Or `.profile.sh`? Still valid?

Comment: Additionally, there is absolutely nothing "invalid" about a filename containing dots. `this.is.a.spreadsheet.xlsx` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @spicekermann am not using rails templates here so I need to check it at my controllers and send json response to react-redux Api call

Comment: @Tom Lord. I have check your string syntax and it shows invalid when passed through the code. so you are wrong on this The counter is working perfectly

Comment: I think what Tom was trying to say is that his example is a valid file name and it has only one extension. Your assumption is wrong: A dot doesn't always separate a filename from an extension because a dot might be part of the name or have special meaning like the dot at the beginning of the name).

Comment: @spickermann okay I now understand Please let me ask you is checking files dot extensions not part of the security measures. if a user tries to upload nancy.php.jpg. is there anything wrong in asking the user to rename his uploading filename by removing the dots before uploading

Comment: @NancyMooree Correct. Requiring a filename to only contain one `.` does not make your system secure.Just because you've prevented someone uploading `my_file.jpg.exe` or whatever, this has got nothing to do with preventing them from actually uploading a malicious file!

Comment: Thanks Sir Tom Lord, am sorry i mis-interpreted your comment above. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply count the '.' if it occurs more than once means its invalid. You can do the following for that.

```
if filename.count('.') > 1 # assuming filename is string 
  print 'Invalid'
else
  print 'Valid'
end
```

Comment: It does not work if you need .tar.gz :) Just saying

Comment: these types of exceptions should be handled for this solution :P

Comment: I'd rather use `File#extname` and validate the extension against a list of whitelisted extensions. I know is not what you asked @NancyMooree but I think is a better approach on whatever are you trying to solve.

Comment: @Vishal Agree, your solution works perfectly fine on the question. I think the question is bad. There is nothing wrong with .tar.gz or having `.` in the filename.

Comment: @radubogdan  is anything wrong in getting file extension name like this when you try to upload files as part of the form params['file'].original_filename.split(".").last